Keyboard character issues when accessing Windows & Linux VMMs on a Synology NAS from a MacBook / MacOS
Problem:
When I access a VM from the MacBook via Browser, I get a "^" back, when I press the "<" key.
Setup:

Synology DS224+ with VMM (Virtual Machine Manager)
Windows 11 VM @ DS224+
Linux Mint VM @ DS224+
Raspberry Pi 400 with NOOBS (Debian Bookworm)
MacBook Air as primary Workstation
All systems up-to-date and set to GERMAN Keyboard settings.
Note: However, I prefer the system language to be ENGLISH

Details:

When I access both VMs via Safari or Chrome from the MacBook, I get a "^" back, when I press the "<" key. I get other mismatches for special keys, but most of the keys work as expected (A-z, a-z, !"§$%&/()=? (=Shift&Number-Key).
When I access the VM via Chromium from the RasPi everything works well.

I assume, that the Problem is something in the MacOS (settings). However all Keys work perfectly locally within the MacOS. Any ideas, what I should check or change ?
